# How do I use BeanIO minLength record level

Tags: java, bean-io

I have beanio mappings file for delimeted file and required check is working but minLength is not working. Could you help with this? **Geroge person record line is not showing minLength error for salary empty**.

```
  <record name="detail" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"
   class="com.test.Person">
   <field name="firstName"/>
   <field name="surname"/>
   <field name="salary" minLength="1"/>
   <field name="age" required="true"/>
  </record>
```

Input:

```
John|Smith|300000.00|34
Peter|William|800000.00|
Gregory|Rocky||30
```

Output:

```
[Person [firstName=John, surname=Smith, salary=300000.0, aget=34], Person [firstName=Gregory, surname=Rocky, salary=0.0, aget=30]]
Errors:
3 : age : [Required field not set]
```

Java Code: Update

```
public void readCSVFileUsingBeanIo() throws FileNotFoundException {
        StreamFactory factory = StreamFactory.newInstance();
        factory.loadResource("person.xml");
        StringBuilder rejects = new StringBuilder();

        // read it from the classpath : src/main/resources
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(
                "person.csv"));
        BeanReader reader = factory.createReader("persons", new InputStreamReader(in));
        reader.setErrorHandler(new BeanReaderErrorHandlerSupport() {
            public void invalidRecord(InvalidRecordException ex) throws Exception {
                for (int i = 0, j = ex.getRecordCount(); i < j; i++) {
                    final int ii = i;
                    if (ex.getRecordContext(i).hasErrors()) {

                        ex.getRecordContext(i).getFieldErrors().keySet().stream().forEach(key -> {
                            rejects.append("\n");
                            rejects.append(ex.getRecordContext(ii).getLineNumber() + " : ");
                            rejects.append(ex.getRecordContext(ii).getRecordText() + " Field(" + key + ") : Error "
                                    + ex.getRecordContext(ii).getFieldErrors(key));
                            
                        });
                        rejects.append("\n");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        Object record = null;
        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();

        while ((record = reader.read()) != null) {
            if ("header".equals(reader.getRecordName())) {

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                Map<String, Object> header = (Map<String, Object>) record;
                System.out.println(header.get("fileDate"));
            } else if ("detail".equals(reader.getRecordName())) {
                Person person = (Person) record;
                persons.add(person);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(persons);
        System.out.println("Errors:");
        System.out.println(rejects);
    }
```

Comment: Probably you should show the Java code too.

Comment: I updated with java code pls check thanks for reply

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the `required="true"` attribute on the `salary` field.

```
<field name="salary" minLength="1" required="true" />
```

This then defines the field as required and having a minimum length of 1. This will give you the required behaviour.

The field is treated as optional if you don't set required to true. Even though a field may be optional, it may still have a minimum length  requirement, when the field is present.

Play around with the different combinations of required and minLength and you will understand how BeanIO treat these values, for example try

```
<field name="salary" minLength="1"/>
<field name="salary" minLength="1" required="true" />
<field name="salary" minLength="5"/>
<field name="salary" minLength="5" required="true" />
```

and this input:

```
John|Smith|300000.00|34
Peter|William|800000.00|
Gregory|Rocky||30
John|Doe|1|30
Jane|Doe|100.00|30
```

The [reference guide](https://beanio.github.io/docs/reference-guide/#a12-field) has the following to say about the required attribute on a field:

> Set to true if this field is required. If a field is required and its
> field text is empty, a BeanReader will throw an InvalidRecordException
> when reading the record. Defaults to false.

Answer (score 0):

Change age attribute to `required="false"` or remove it.

```xml
<record name="detail" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" class="com.test.Person">
    <field name="firstName"/>
    <field name="surname"/>
    <field name="salary" minLength="1"/>        
    <field name="age"/>
</record>
```

Comment: Already it is set in code but not working